# Determining Multicollinearity for the given ScatterPlot Matrix

Tags: multicollinearity

Given this data:

[image]

should I be concerned with multicollinearity here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is concern of multicollinearity since the correlation between Education level and Annual Income = .7551 which is > .7.

Comment: Wow, .7 is quite a low threshold for screaming multicollinearity...